# which port to allow through ubuntu firewall

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm networking Win PC's with a ubuntu computer.  ubuntu has no problem seeing, accessing files and printing through the Win PC.  However, Win PC was not allowed to access the ubuntu computer until I disabled the ubuntu firewall.  After that, all is well.
I want to enable the firewall and have installed gufw to allow limited access to the ubuntu computer.  WHICH port or ports do I let through the firewall.

Comment: What software are you using to share data on the Ubuntu machine? `samba`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get list of ports from file called /etc/services. For your ease of use here are ports you need to open for two-way samba communication with Windows and Linux desktop systems.

```
netbios-ns – 137/tcp # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-dgm – 138/tcp # NETBIOS Datagram Service
netbios-ssn – 139/tcp # NETBIOS session service
microsoft-ds – 445/tcp # if you are using Active Directory
```

Other ports:

```
Port 389 (TCP) – for LDAP (Active Directory Mode)
Port 445 (TCP) – NetBIOS was moved to 445 after 2000 and beyond, (CIFS)
Port 901 (TCP) – for SWAT service (not related to client communication)
```

Command To Find Out Required TCP/UDP Ports For SMB/CIFS Networking Protocol

Type the following command:

$ `grep -i NETBIOS /etc/services`

Sample outputs:

```
netbios-ns  137/tcp             # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns  137/udp
netbios-dgm 138/tcp             # NETBIOS Datagram Service
netbios-dgm 138/udp
netbios-ssn 139/tcp             # NETBIOS session service
netbios-ssn 139/udp
```

reference: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-samba-to-communicate-with-other-windowslinux-systems/

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.  Using the GUFW application, it is easy to allow access to the ports listed.

Comment: @wolf981 please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!